# How to call an event from another event

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have an event like `static private void HandleClientEventCB(SPD.SPD_eventType type, SPD.SPD_event this_event, object passback)` in a class `public class SPURTServer`, I need to call this event outside another event
Here the '`**SPD_eventType**`' is enumeration under different project that means '`namespace Spo.SPDlib`' and '`public class SPD`' here the value for that enum  is SPD_clientEvent = 5,

and `SPD.SPD_event` is a struct like `public struct SPD_event`  and passback value is null.

So I called like this in outside event like shown below

`SPURTServer.HandleClientEventCB(Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_eventType.SPD_clientEvent, Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_event,object passback);`

but it is throwing error like "Invalid expression term 'object'" I am not sure what about the other two arguements. Can anybody guide me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call, you need to remove the word Object.

so:

```
SPURTServer.HandleClientEventCB(Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_eventType.SPD_clientEvent,
    Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_event,
    passback);
```

or cast it:

```
SPURTServer.HandleClientEventCB(Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_eventType.SPD_clientEvent,
    Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_event,
    (object)passback);
```

Assuming that passback is a valid object in the scope of the call.

Edit: based on the comments below:

What you're doing is passing the type of the event, not an instance of the event itself.

SPD_Event is a definition of your data, but you have created an instance of it.

You'd need to to something like

```
var newEvent = new Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_event();
newEvent.WhatEverProperties = whatNeedsToBeSet;

SPURTServer.HandleClientEventCB(Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_eventType.SPD_clientEvent,
    newEvent,
    null);
```

Comment: but now i am getting error 'Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_event' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Ahh, that's likely becauuse Spo.SPDlib.SPD.SPD_event isn't an instance of the class, it's just the class itself. you need to have an actual event, not just the type of event.

Comment: It might help if you can post the whole method around this problem line.

Comment: SPD_event is a struct like public struct SPD_event which will carry data

Comment: Russ you need anything more,,SPD_event is struct which will carry around 11 values

Comment: Updated my answer to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: Sorry Russ,, i forgot basic things ,in the scenario u created i can pass 'newEvent' itself in call,,anyway thanks